# How to get a Listenable from a Riverpod Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to use `go_router` (https://pub.dev/packages/go_router#redirection) together with `Riverpod`.

I have a `Provider` and a `StreamProvider`, which I would like to combine into a `Listenable` so it can be used as the `refreshListenable` param of `GoRouter`.

I guess I need combine the `Provider` and a `StreamProvider` into some kind of `Provider` (how?).

What is the easiest way to create a `Listenable` from a `Provider`?

Edit: I understand that this 'negates' the point of Riverpod, but the app is all setup with Riverpod already and I would just like to add go_router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much simpler way as ChangeNotifier can be used with Riverpod.  There is a Gihtub issue on Riverpod's Github repo on this.
https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/884

Answered by Tim Whitting on Gihtub (his code and comments below):

You can use ChangeNotifier with flutter_riverpod.

```
final myNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<MyNotifier>((ref) => MyNotifier());
class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  void refresh(){
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then you have to watch the provider where you are trying to pass the Listenable.

```
// 1.0.0-dev riverpod
refreshListenable: ref.watch(myNotifierProvider)
// 0.14.0
refreshListenable: watch(myNotifierProvider) // using a Consumer / ConsumerWidget
```

And use elsewhere

```
// 1.0.0-dev riverpod
ref.read(myNotifierProvider.notifier).refresh();
// 0.14.0
context.read(myNotifierProvider.notifier).refresh();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do so using StateNotifier instead of ChangeNotifier ? I tried to do so, but couldn't make it work

Answer (score 2):

I solved it as follows:

```
class AListenable extends ValueNotifier {
  AListenable(value) : super(value);

  void changeValue(newValue) {
    value = newValue;
  }
}

   
 final aListenableInstance = AListenable(false);

 final myProvider = Provider((ref) {

  final my2ndProviderValue = ref.watch(my2ndProvider);

  if (my2ndProviderValue is AsyncError || my2ndProviderValue is AsyncLoading) {
    aListenableInstance.changeValue(false);
    return false;
  }

  aListenableInstance.changeValue(true);
  return true;
});

final _router = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: aListenableInstance,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the riverpod intensively, you can navigate with it directly, without go_router.
There is interesting issue here: [river_pod issues 1122](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/1122)